# Why are certain indefinite integrals unsolvable while their corresponding definite integrals are solvable (in a specified interval)?

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, indefinite-integrals

I'm going to take an example to elaborate my question.

My teacher said that - $\int \sin(x^3)dx$ is unsolvable for all x.
Just recently, he said that $\int_{-\pi/6}^{\pi/6} \sin(x^3) = 0$. Now I get why its zero but my question is -

- Indefinite Integration is an anti-derivative process. If a function can be differentiated, then why can't it be integrated so as to get its primitive? Are those functions like some "unsolved mysteries of mathematics" ? Because if we're integrating something then its almost understood that its primitive exists (at least thats what I think).
- What about an expression makes it non-integrable?
- Can we look (or examine it a little bit) and say that the expression is integrable or not? If so, what are the things we should look out for?

Comment: Definite integrals are not an anti-derivative process. Anti-derivatives can be one way to solve them, but there are lots of ways to solve them. Also, even when you can’t “solve” and indefinite integral, there is a function which is the indefinite integral. You just can’t write that function down in terms of known functions.

Comment: Whether an indefinite integral has a closed form is a highly technical area. That doesn’t mean the indefinite integral doesn’t exist, it just means it doesn’t have a certain form. Just as some real numbers are irrational, some indefinite integrals exist and  can’t be written in a closed form in terms of other “usual” functions. In any even, these functions are integrable. The functions which are actually not integrable are highly strange, and in particular, are not continuous.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews 's comment is spot on. Let me complete it by saying that computing an antiderivative is akin to finding the value of a function on its entire domain. This is far, far more complex than guessing the value of said function at certain points only (which is what the definite integral on a given interval is).

Comment: Just to add, not every continuous function can be differentiated. There are continuous functions that are nowhere differentiable.

Comment: @StefanLafon I'm still not clear. Why can't we integrate a function for its entire domain if we can differentiate it for the same ?

Comment: Point taken. My explanation was not so much about antiderivative vs derivative, but rather about antiderivative at all points vs at some points.

Comment: But my question still remains. Why can't we solve some indefinite integrals fully ? I get what your trying to say that we can tell about its behaviour at certain points but why can't we just solve it fully?

Answer (score 5):

Whether an indefinite integral has a closed form is a highly technical area.

That doesn’t mean the indefinite integral doesn’t exist, it just means it doesn’t have a certain form.

Just as some real numbers are irrational, some indefinite integrals exist and  can’t be written in a closed form in terms of other “usual” functions. In any event, these functions are integrable.

---

A useful non-integral example of a similar thing is the Lambert W-function. Given an $x\geq 0,$ $y=W(x)$ if $x=ye^y.$

We can’t write $W$ in terms of “elementary functions.” (Proving that requires some extremely tricky techniques.) But we can compute $W$ numerically, and we can tell specific values, like $W(0)=0, W(e)=1.$ We can prove things about $W.,$ like that it is an increasing function.

Mathematicians do this a lot. We can prove properties of $F(x)=\int\sin(x^3)\,dx,$ even if we can’t write $F(x)$ in a useful way.

---

There are functions which are actually not integrable, but they are highly strange, and in particular, those functions cannot be written in a closed form, either.

Comment: What do you mean by "closed form" ?

Comment: It means in terms of a composition of some set of known functions. The indefinite integral for $\sin(x^3)$ can be written as: $$\int_{0}^{x}\sin(t^3)\,dt +C,$$ but that isn’t a close form, because integrals are complex. The usual allowed “elementary” functions are addition, multiplication, division, constants, $e^x,$ logarithms, trig functions, addition, multiplication, polynomials, and inverses of these functions, where applicable. So $\tan^{-1}(e^x\ln x)+x^2$ is a closed form.

Comment: Okay. Thank you

Comment: A  fairly simple example: The derivative of a polynomial is a polynomial so the derivative of a rational function  is a rational function. But $\int (1/x)dx (x>0)$ is not a rational function.

Comment: Even though you brought it up, do not forget elementary functions vs non elementary functions. If you let one use any academically recognized functions, then you can find $\int \sin\left(x^3\right) dx$ in terms of the [Generalized Exponential Integral function](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/En-Function.html) etc.